# bootstrap dynamically centering columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a horizontal bar and I want to put sections into that bar. I can't think of a way to center them dynamically -- ie if I have 1 section its put to the center, if I have 2 sections they're put straddling the center, if I have 3 sections the middle section is centered and the other two are on either side, etc. I'm changing the number of sections with javascript so I can't just solve this for a particular number of sections.

How should I do so? Also I realized that the section names aren't showing up on the snippet (but they are on my actual site).

```css
.middle-section {
  height: 100px;
  
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F6F7F8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: translate(0%,-50%);
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = 'container-fluid'>
<div class = 'middle-section'>
    <div class = 'row'>
 <div class ='col-md-2'>
   Section 
 </div>
 <div class ='col-md-2'>
   
   Section
 </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why not using BS grid system?

Comment: No, you are trying to use your own `.middle-section` class, while you should use BS classes like `pull-*`,`col-md-offset-*`,`.col-md-pull-*`,`.col-md-push-*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used flexbox to solve your problem, just add some divs to try it :

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bj2m4bf/1/)

You can chose to justify all your divs : `center`, `space-around` or `space-beween`

```css
.middle-section {
  height: 100px;
  
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F6F7F8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  
}

.customrow {display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:space-around; }

.customrow-child {border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div class = 'container-fluid'>
  <div class = 'middle-section'>
    <div class = 'row customrow'>
       <div class ='col-md-2 row-child customrow-child'>
         Section 
       </div>
       <div class ='col-md-2 row-child customrow-child'>
   
         Section
       </div>
      
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for this. I really need to learn how to use flexbox (am doing so right now). Any idea on vertically centering it? I tried just doing padding-top: 50px on row-child but since I used transform with one of the parent elements it doesn't center it quite right. Unless I'm wrong and that's not why it's not centering correctly haha.

Comment: You can use `flex-direction:column` for your children to be vertically aligned. If you are trying to learn flex box, let me advise you two very good websites : [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a complete guide and [Flexy Boxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) Is a sandbox to try everything.

Comment: Nice, you should find pretty much everything on these websites. If you still have questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: @Relisora: I'm sorry, but I had to down vote your answer. Because you have violated bootstrap framework. Don't overwrite default bootstrap classes. Add a custom class and then write your custom stylings to it along with the bootstrap class. Once again sorry for the critic vote. But hope you will learn something. :)

Comment: @JeradRutnam Hey, thank's for the comment, I updated my code trying to keep all the native Bootstrap divs and creating custom ones for what i'm changing. I hope i did not miss anything and my answer now will help the community.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding an offset,

This is just a non violated bootstrap solution. But yes of course there are many work around for this. But this is an quick solution by bootstrap default classes.

HTML,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row middle-section">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4">Section</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">Section</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS,

```
.middle-section {
  height: 50px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F6F7F8;
  border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ywdwnq2s/2/

You can find more details in the bootstrap documentation, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

---

To make it more dynamically you can override the defaults little bit by adding some additional styling,

HTML,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row middle-section">
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 inner-section">Section </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 inner-section">Section</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 inner-section">Section</div>
    </div> 
 </div>
```

CSS,

```
.middle-section {
  height: 50px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F6F7F8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.inner-section {
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ywdwnq2s/4/

Comment: Person who down voted the answer please explain your vote. Will help to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply `Text-align:center`

```css
.middle-section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F6F7F8;
  
  border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.middle-section .row{
  text-align:center;
  }
.middle-section .row .col-md-2{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = 'container-fluid'>
<div class = 'middle-section'>
    <div class = 'row'>
 <div class ='col-md-2'>
   Section 
 </div>
  <div class ='col-md-2'>
   Section
 </div>
  <div class ='col-md-2'>
   Section
 </div>
 <div class ='col-md-2'>
   Section
 </div>
 </div>
    
</div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/sank8893/osz13nd8/1/